# Objective C - removing default chevron glyph for back button in iOS SDK 8.4

Tags: objective-c, back-button

i'm seeking help in removing the default "<" symbol placed before the back button text in a navigation controller going from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB.

in ViewControllerA i have:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back to A"
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.image = nil;
}
```

the result - when segued into ViewControllerB - is: "< Back to A" in the new navigation controller whereas I want just "Back to A".

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using storyboards? If you are, you get the desired result by drag-dropping a UIBarButtonItem to where the default back button shows up. That's it. Set the desired text and arrow will not show up.

**EDIT:**

To make the custom back button function, connect an IBAction to it.

in view controller B:

```
- (IBAction)backToControllerA {
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Connect the action to the button in IB.

Comment: i am using storyboards - i dropped a "bar button item" on the top left of the "navigation bar". the button animates a click but does not do anything. in particular i want to it desegue.